# How to wait until DOM has loaded before adding script tags to <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, meteor

I'm implementing this [Developr theme](http://themeforest.net/item/developr-fully-responsive-admin-skin/2085628) from themeforest into a Meteor app.

I'm currently accomplishing this by placing the javascripts in question to `/public` and appending them using jQuery:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  $('head').append('<script src="/template_stuff.js"></script>');
  // .. all 7 scripts or so
});
```

If the required scripts are placed in `/client/js/`, it appears that they either run too early or before the DOM is done loading. If they are placed directly in the header of the main html file, they seem to bug out the same way.

Am I missing something here - is there a more elegant way to make the scripts load after DOM has loaded?

Comment: Why not use jQuery `$.getScript()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: You don't need to add them to the head if you're waiting until the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods for waiting until the DOM has loaded to inject your scripts:

- Meteor.startup (as you illustrated)
- jQuery's document ready:  `$(function () { ... })`
- script tag at the bottom of your layout template

Regarding elegance, I use a handlebars helper as it allows me to consolidate all 'after body' code in one place.  Then use jQuery's document ready as needed.

For example,

```
// in client/handlebars.js

Handlebars.registerHelper('afterBody', function(name, options) {

  function isMobileSafari() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
           navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
  }

  if (isMobileSafari()) {
    $(function () {
      FastClick.attach(document.body)
    })
  }

  //// load scripts however you want...
  // $(function () {
  //   $.getScript as Daniel suggests
  //   $('body').append as you have
  //   pure js: document.createElement('script')
  // })

})


// in client/main.html (using mini-pages router)

<template name="layout_no_header">
  {{{yield}}}

  {{afterBody}}
</template>

<template name="layout">
  {{> header}}

  {{{yield}}}

  {{afterBody}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery getScript()

```
(function ($) {
    $.getScript("/template_stuff.js");
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a different problem. It sounds like the 3rd party code is being wrapped in a closure and is not working correctly. Try and place them inside the `client/compatibility` folder. This will prevent it from being wrapped in a closure, which can solve 3rd party problems. Be sure the load order inside of here is correct, it loads files in alphabetical order inside of a folder. ([load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp))

If that doesn't work, find out where the code is being executed and comment out the call. Then load your html inside of a template, even if it's just a 'page' template with all the html. Create a `js` file for the template and call the methods in the templates rendered callback.

```
// Execute this function when myPage template is rendered
Template.myPage.rendered = function() {
  stuff.init();
  stuff2.run();
};
```

Note, the to call `stuff2`, etc.. you'll likely need to have it's script in the compatibility folder so you can reach the namespaces from the `template_stuff.js`.